# Chrome extension that adds icon to omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've done a lot of googling and have come up dry on this. I feel like I've seen it before but I can't find any extension in my arsenal that allows this.

What I would like to do is have a chrome extension that can place an icon (or text, even better) at the right side of the omnibox in chrome.

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [Page Action](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html).

In which application should we use Page Actions? If you want to add your extension's features to a few specific pages, use Page Actions. Otherwise, if you want to add features in most pages, use [Browser Actions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) instead. Text cannot be added in Page Actions, though it can be added in Browser Actions with limitation by using Badge (a bit of text that is layered over the icon).

Some good examples of this kind of extensions to help you picture the concept:

- [Google's RSS Subscription Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd). This extension only injects if it finds RSS feeds on a page
- [Lyrics for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oglbipcbkmlknhfhabolnniekmlhfoek). This extension only injects its scripts in YouTube pages, create a new div next to the video to display the lyrics of a music vid.